# How to configure DNS Records for .sol domain so Brave recognizes it?

Tags: nft, sol

Brave browser now supports resolving .sol domains https://brave.com/solana-name-service/
But what I'm curious about is how can I configure the DNS records for my .sol domain?

I see in the Bonfida UX there's options for setting Records on the domain like IPFS, SHDW, etc, but what about standard DNS records like A, CNAME? Are these not supported or if they are, how can I set them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some digging I found an answer.

Currently, Brave resolves .sol DNS via the Bonfida Name Resolver [here](https://github.com/Bonfida/name-resolver). We can see in the [name resolver logic](https://github.com/Bonfida/name-resolver/blob/f0cba275c6049c61297d77ec7add84831208f593/src/derivation.rs#L45-L48) that it first checks the `url` record, followed by the `IPFS`, `ARWV`, then `SHDW` records in that order. In all cases, it doesn't work like a CNAME where your .sol fully-qualified domain name remains in the address bar. Rather, Brave [will do a redirect](https://github.com/Bonfida/name-resolver/blob/f0cba275c6049c61297d77ec7add84831208f593/src/derivation.rs#L71-L86) to the url if a url record is present, a subpath of cloudflare-ipfs.com/ipfs for `IPFS` records, a subpath of `arweave.net` for `ARWV` records, or a subpath of `shdw-drive.genesysgo.net` for `SHDW` records.

To get the CNAME/A record behavior typically seen in traditional DNS, I've opened [a Github issue](https://github.com/Bonfida/name-resolver/issues/5). It seems like Bonfida has plans to support such functionality, and I will be contributing to a new SNS IP repo to add support for this. I'll update the answer once it's supported.

Comment: For those who visit this page now. A and CNAME both got implemented.