# Brave, Solana name service,

Tags: sol

I've been working on setting up my .sol domain and this answer appears correct by existing documentation. I found this previously: [How to configure DNS Records for .sol domain so Brave recognizes it?](https://solana.stackexchange.com/questions/6787/how-to-configure-dns-records-for-sol-domain-so-brave-recognizes-it) But that answer does not seem to work for me.

Additionally, Pyth.sol is used an example in the documentation of the value of a .sol domain. However, looking at the pyth.sol record neither url, IPRS, ARWV, nor SHDW are set. BUT content is set to their url: pyth.network.

I have both content and url set in my sns domain....and Brave still fails to resolve my .sol domain.

Curious if there is someone who has Brave resolution of SNS domains working correctly? Or did Pyth do something special?